# Reduce width of a loop type model

Tags: modeling

I have a sort of loop type model(something like racing track) where there are 2 paralel curve-typed vertex loops. They're connected together like this
(simplified image):
[image: The image]

- Red lines - edges of outer loop
- Yellow lines - edges of inner loop
- Magenta lines - the connections between loops
- Green dots - vertices
- Blue dots - joint middle points(not actual model data, just imaginary thing for explanation)

What I want is to scale the magenta edges down(move green vertices which are joined with the magenta edges closer to each other) without changing the position of the blue points(the place where the magenta edges are or the place where the 2 connected vertices are). I could do it manually(select each 2 vertices and press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>, for example), but it would take a lot of time. Is there any automated way to do it?

Comment: You can ring select these edges and scale them done with 'individual origins' as pivot center.

Comment: This works, thanks. I'd reccomend you to create answer for this so that I can mark it as corrected and you gain reputation;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edge Slide

The idea is to pick one of the boundary loops and [slide it](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-slide) by pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in order to make it move next to the other other.

[image]

In order to use the middle point lines as a pivot, you should create a third loop in the middle with for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>....

[image]

...and then slide each loop by the same factor.

[image]

Comment: That is even a more beautiful workflow

Comment: @Dan Indeed! Carlo, this is nice!;)

Comment: I think the fastest is the one suggested (but sadly not yet written as an answer ) by @Yvain. This was proposed as a second alternative. Thanks for the appreciation anyway!

Answer (score 4):

- Set the *Pivot Point* to *Median Point* or *Individual Origins*:

  [image]
- Select the inner *Edge Loop* with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Scale <kbd>S</kbd> it to your desired size

  [image]

---

**In Addition**

The 'middle points' of your magenta edges will change. If you want the blue dots unaffected you will need to create an Edge Loop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) between the inner and outer edge before you scale the inner edge:

[image]

---

**Edit**

If your shape is not circular you can try this:

- Select the outer edge and extrude it <kbd>E</kbd> and confirm without translation, scaling or rotation
- Switch to *Edge Select* and select all 'magenta' edges (e.g. *Select* > *Edge Rings*)
- *Pivot Point* to *Individual Origins*
- Scale <kbd>S</kbd>
- Select and delete the unwanted *Edge Loop* <kbd>X</kbd>

[image]

Comment: This only works with circular shape. However, I have a shape that's more complex.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis Post edited. Maybe there is a better solution, but i hope it helps.